# Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for all but Windows Administrator login

Tags: sql-server, oracle, linked-server

I have a few dozen linked servers, MSSQL, Teradata and Oracle. These are on SQL Server 2019. Oracle servers are using OraOLEDB.Oracle 19c client. They are all created with the same parametrized script.

Error Message:

> Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "XXXXXXX".

Edit:
Works with the login of the Windows Administrator but not any other SA login.

Error number is 7302 but is not a DLL registration issue

The script was used to create the linked servers on SQL Server 1 and SQL Server 2, on #1 all works great. On #2, MSSQL and Teradata servers are good but Oracle servers only work with the account used to install Oracle. I have tried granting all rights to Everyone on Oracle base and Oracle Home for testing, but that didn't help.

All linked servers are set up to use remote user and remote password for all logins. Below is the part of the script that executes sp_addlinkedsrvlogin.

```
SET @SQL = N'EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=@ServerName,@useself=N''False'',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=@UserName,@rmtpassword=@Password'

EXEC $(TargetServer).master.dbo.sp_executesql 
    @stmt=@SQL
    ,@params = N'@ServerName nvarchar(250), @UserName nvarchar(250), @Password nvarchar(250)'
    ,@ServerName=@ServerName
    ,@UserName=@UserName
    ,@Password=@Password
```

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: @Ronaldo, the error message is Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server

Comment: What about the oracle log? do you see the attempted login failed on the oracle server? Could it be that you have any special character on the password that is causing problem?

Comment: @Ronaldo, the error is entirely on the client end. The same user id/password are used on server #1. I don't have access to the Oracle server logs, but the message suggests that the SQL Server cannot create an instance of the provider, so it isn't even attempting to access the Oracle server.

Comment: This is a bit outside of my lane, but when I googled ' Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle"', I got lot's of promising looking hits, including some other threads on SE.   I'd say Google is your friend. Use your friend.

Comment: And you don't get an "Microsoft SQL Server, Error" number?

Comment: I assume Microsoft SQL Server, Error 7302. so check https://www.sqldbadiaries.com/2010/12/27/cannot-create-an-instance-of-ole-db-provider-oraoledb-oracle-for-linked-server/ and https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/topic/you-encounter-error-messages-when-you-execute-linked-server-queries-without-the-required-providers-installed-18829316-025b-096b-bf18-5e24fea1709d

Comment: @miracle173, I have and that is not my issue. The linked servers work with the login of the Windows administrator  on the server but not with any other SA login. Btw, yes, it is 7302, just not a DLL registration issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be the AllowInProcess flag on the OraOLEDB.Oracle provider.

This solved the problem:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'OraOLEDB.Oracle', N'AllowInProcess', 1
```